Windows Explorer Shift+Right Click Commands for Python versions
I used to have scripts that would update the registry editor (regedit) to add multiple python versions so that when I shift+right click, I can select one and a command window linked to that python version would open.  Why would I want this, because there are two softwares that use their own python version and then I want to use the python version I have for my standalone scripts.
It should work such that when I type python --version it is linked to the corrected mapped path.
I thought I could just do this:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Python3]
@="Anaconda3 (Run Here)"
"Extended"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Python3\command]
@="cmd.exe /k \"C:\\Users\\Celeste.Wilson\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\python.exe\" \"%V\""

And then do one for the version of the software I have but they all only go to whatever is 1st in the environmental variables.
I remember I had to do something to make it work.  I've googled everything and can't find it and I can't find those scripts.
